# Input type Month HTML with javascript

Tags: javascript, date, input

Please help  me. and Let me know . I required:

I have one drop down in which the value are Monthly, Quarterly, Halfyearly, Yearly. this will be implemented according to financial year means April to next year march.

I want when I select Monthly all months are appended in input type. when i select quarter suppose if i select Q1, only April. May, June month are appended. if i select h1 halfyearly , first 6 month are append on input.

I am using html  input type month in my app.

If There are some more option, please help me.

Comment: Please show us some code. What have you tried?

Comment: Firstly I required the data for quarterly, Halfyearly and yearly. I am getting only financial year right now.

Comment: getFinancialYear:function(){
          var fiscalYear = '';
          var dateObj=new Date();
          var monthObj=dateObj.getMonth()+1;
          if(monthObj<4){
                fiscalYear = (dateObj.getFullYear()-1)+ "-"+dateObj.getFullYear();
          }else{
                fiscalYear = dateObj.getFullYear()+ "-"+(dateObj.getFullYear()+1);
          }
          
           console.info(monthNames[dateObj.getMonth()]);
      },

Comment: var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

Comment: You're going to get more help if you read the how to on asking questions. I'd put that code in the question too.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this fiddle it may help.

```
var arr=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];

function selectchange(){
    var x = document.getElementById("sel").value;
  alert(x);
  if(x=="h1"){
  for(i=0;i<6;i++){
  document.getElementById("input").innerHTML+= arr[i]+",";
  }
  }
   if(x=="m1"){
  for(i=0;i<12;i++){
  document.getElementById("input").innerHTML+= arr[i]+",";
  }
  }  
  if(x=="q1"){
  for(i=3;i<6;i++){
  document.getElementById("input").innerHTML+= arr[i]+",";
  }
  }  
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/29391/)

Comment: <input type="month" class="month-wise" id="month-cal">  I am using html input type month in my app.

Comment: i want to use this.

Comment: I don't get your requirement basically but if your are trying to filter months from input type month may be it is not possible